# regex for getting text inside [bbcode]

Tags: javascript, regex

How get the text inside a custom bbcode,

```
[gallery] get this text [/gallery].
```

I am using this regex but it wont work

```
/^(.*)\[gallery.*?\[\/gallery\](.*)$/gmi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(new) try :

```
/\[gallery\](.*)\[\/gallery\]/g
```

to return the value use

```
var result = str.match(regex); alert(result[1]);
```

Comment: like this `str.replace(/[gallery](*.)+[\/gallery]/i, '\$1')`

Comment: var result = str.match(regex); alert(result[1]);

Comment: getting SyntaxError: invalid quantifier

Comment: Depending on the regex engine, this won't work if there are multiple gallery tags. The regex will match everything between the first opening gallery tag and the last closing gallery tag. To be safe, throw a `?` after the greedy `*` to make it look like `/\[gallery\](.*?)\[\/gallery\]/g`.

Comment: @HowToPlease I suppose you would want to do it the lazy way, (*.)+  to handle multiple tags within the same string

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there may be some attributes after inside your tag.

Try this:

```
/\[gallery[^\]]*\](.*)\[\/gallery\]/gi
```

Comment: getting SyntaxError: invalid quantifier

Comment: This answer attempts to get a little too cute when searching for the opening tag.  It's not necessary here.  We already know that the opening tag needs to look exactly like this: `[gallery]`